# No known package when getting name for resource number 0xffffffff

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing, logcat, instrumentation

```
W/ResourceType( 2739): No known package when getting name for resource number 0xffffffff
I/System.out( 2739): Resource not found for -1. Moving on.
```

When I run automated UI tests I see the above two lines basically for every view which is shown. So far I could not isolate the "problem" any further. The UI tests pass more/less without problems and the UI looks just fine. When starting the app regularly, not from instrumentation, the logs do not appear.

This output, except for being noisy, does not come with any exception or immediate problem. So this is more a curiosity thing.

I am pretty sure it is not misuse of TextView.setText(), because everything works as expected and the log is only visible during instrumentation.

Can anybody give me a clue what to look for?

Answer (score 0):

As I found out the source for these logs is the calabash android logic I am using, see https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/70ebbd9bae30ae78a7693a8e8d0d1b7033b3e11e/ruby-gem/test-server/instrumentation-backend/src/sh/calaba/instrumentationbackend/query/ViewMapper.java#L78

Comment: were you able to muffle these somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate that this is an old post but found it while investigating this issue.

This warning was moved to calabash-android-server (and changed slightly since this post. From the next version of the server it should stop raising this error.

We're also looking in to why the error occurs so I'll update this post if we make any progress.